# Meteorjs installation error

Tags: javascript, macos, terminal, meteor

I am trying to install meteorjs on a mac, however, I keep getting this error message from the terminal window. Can someone please explain to me what is happening or refer me to the proper documentation for this particular problem?

Here is the output:

```
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
.meteor/packages/d3/.1.0.0.1ow7fwj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/web.cordova/packages/d3.js.map: (Empty error message)
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Installation failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a curl issue and that you're trying to download from a web server via HTTPS.

The curl command in the script doesn't do certificate validation, so I'm betting it's a timeout issue unless you've changed the curl function as written in the script.